# Convertor form JSON to Objective C like SudzC

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, sudzc

Is there any convertor that used to convert JSON web-service to Objective C code like Sudzc that use SOAP protocol.

Comment: Do you mean a JSON parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Also if you want to have more detail.... check these

1. Convert the JSON string into an NSDictionary using tools like yajl, JSONKit or iOS5 JSON
2. Use a tool like [Jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor) to convert this NSDictionary to a real Objective-C class with typed properties, nested properties, arrays etc.
3. [Apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)